# Unable to save access point policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3-access-points

This is my access point policy:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:ap-south-1:my_account_number:accesspoint/my_access_point_name/object/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to save this policy. I am getting a Access Denied error:

[image]

Note: That I am using root account

Comment: What's in the "API Response"? What error it throwing?

Comment: Same error: Access Denied

Comment: Do you have **S3 Block Public Access** activated on that bucket? By default, it will block the creation of Bucket Policies. If you turn off the two Block Public Access options that mention 'bucket policy', does it allow you to save the policy?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I agree with you and I'll try again after turning off the above mentioned **S3 Block Public Access**. But the policy above is access point policy. Does **S3 Block Public Access** effect **Access Point Policy** too?

Comment: Oops, no, it won't affect an Access Point Policy. My mistake. If you are using a Root Account, it is strange that you are getting an Access Denied error. It is possible on things like Bucket Policies where DENY statements remove permissions, but I wouldn't think it possible for an Access Point policy. Does the "API Response" shown in your picture contain any additional information?

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything after consulting with my co-worker. We came to a conclusion that we should AWS CLI. Then it worked. I could access my S3 bucket through prod server as well as local host. Just ask ChatGPT "How to login in aws cli in ec2".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).